# Force compile with MSBuild on local environment and use dotnet on continous integration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core

I have one project configured with [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/josephrodriguez/skyland-pipeline) for Nuget deployments. Recently I decide add support for .Net Core Framework. On continuous integration environment `dotnet` is used to compile, run unit tests and pack the project, but when I added a `project.json` and compile with Visual Studio 2015 `dotnet` is used instead **MSBuild**. So I have in the [project](https://github.com/josephrodriguez/Skyland.Pipeline) folder the `.csproj` and `project.json` files.

**QUESTION:**

- There is any way to configure Visual Studio to use always **MSBuild** with `.csproj` instead `dotnet` with `project.json` and leave the use of these for continuous integration only?

Comment: Drop .NET Core support in VS2015 and switch to VS2017.

Comment: I have to configure something on VS2017?

Comment: You have to move to VS2017 and migrate .NET Core projects from project.json to native csproj. Please read about .NET Core SDK preview 3 (and above) from http://dot.net and VS2015 only works with preview 2.x which are out of date. You can read my latest blog post at https://blog.lextudio.com for an example, as I recently migrated #SNMP Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is any way to configure Visual Studio to use always MSBuild with .csproj instead dotnet with project.json and leave the use of these for continuous integration only?

You can use the dotnet migrate command to migrate a project.json project to the csproj format. This command will also migrate any project-to-project references you have in your
project.json file automatically. for more information, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-migrate

The following blogs provide an example about migrate project.json to csproj for your reference(please check the phase “Upgrading project.json projects”)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/